How to neglect duplicate file to not to copy in the destination folder?
I am trying to get some of the zip files from a specific folder to my destination folder which contains a specific date range added in the file name so for example zip file contains a name such as FE1_ABS_202404240600.zip, FE1_ABS_202404240601.zip, FE1_ABS_202404240610.zip, etc

Now I have written a code which does extracts the file but after about 5 or 6 copy. It fails. Error message contains that " the file '[sourcepath]\FE1_ABS_202404240600.zip' already exist.

I am unsure how can I remove this issue and copy all file between such date range
public static void getFilesNames() {
  string startDate = "04/24/2024";
  string endDate = "06/03/2024";
  DateTime tmpDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
  DateTime tmpDate2 = DateTime.ParseExact(endDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);

  string startdt = tmpDate1.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
  string enddt = tmpDate2.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

  DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Parse(startDate);
  DateTime dtEnd = DateTime.Parse(endDate);

  string sourcePath = @ "E:\ReceivedFile\";
  string destPath = @ " E:\ProcessedFile\";

  do {
    string partialName = "ABS";
    DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
    FileInfo[] filesInDir = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFiles("*" + partialName + "_" + startdt + "*.zip*");

    foreach(FileInfo foreachPath in filesInDir) {
      string fullName = foreachPath.FullName;
      File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourcePath, foreachPath.ToString()), Path.Combine(destPath, foreachPath.ToString()));
    }
  } while (dtStart < dtEnd);
}

Checked if I have my duplicate zip files but seems I have unique files in my source. So why showing duplicate file error?

Applying the ToString() method to a FileInfo instance produce the fullname (including the path). So I am not sure how this will work even the first time.

Files in a folder are not in any order by date.  So you code is stopping on the first file that is outside the end date.  Why do you need the do/while loop?  Do you want to get only the top directory or all children as well?  Use the search option if you want the children : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-8.0#system-io-directory-getfiles(system-string-system-string-system-io-searchoption)

@jdweng I do not have Children under that folder. ReceivedFile is the Parent Folder and inside that are all Zip Files no subfolders exist in ReceivedFile Folder. In addition, I am doing do while so that it copies all Zip files between specified dates.

@Steve You can also do is foreachPath.Name but it does the same thing.

If you run the script twice wouldn't you get duplicates?

@jdweng I am not running twice. Yes if I ran twice there would be duplicates but when it goes under loop it stays under "04/24/2024" date. And due to that it was trying to paste the file which already exist

@jdweng This was the first time execution and issue occurred. So there was no possibility of running the code twice.

Solved the issue for this. This was the problem with the loop which was staying in StartDate. And incrementing the date would also require to go till enddate
public static void getFilesNames() {
  var selectedDates = new List < DateTime ? > ();
  DateTime ? StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact("04/24/2024", "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
  DateTime ? EndDate = DateTime.ParseExact("06/03/2024", "MM/dd/yyyy", null);

  string sourcePath = @ "E:\ReceivedPath";
  string destPath = @ "E:\ProcessedFile\";

  string partialName = "ABS";
  DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);

  do {
    string startdt = StartDate.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    string enddt = EndDate.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

    FileInfo[] filesInDir = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFiles("*" + partialName + "_" + startdt + "*.zip*");

    selectedDates.Add(StartDate);
    foreach(FileInfo foreachPath in filesInDir) {
      string fullName = foreachPath.FullName;
      File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourcePath, foreachPath.Name), Path.Combine(destPath, foreachPath.Name));
    }
    StartDate = StartDate.Value.AddDays(1);
  } while (StartDate <= EndDate);
}

